# Can the X++ language be used for the following development?

Tags: x++

I'm interested in developing primarily games and websites. Is X++ a suitable language for this?

Comment: Not a real question. (What *are* you asking?)

Comment: Okay, bods. Cleaned up the question as best I could. user287745, if I'd inadvertently changed the intent of your question, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of your "Can it be used?" *title*, possibly, but it seems to be targeted to business oriented applications:

> X++ is an object-oriented language with similarities to C#. X++ is part of the MorphX development platform that you use to construct accounting and business management systems. <sup>(a)</sup>

That means, in terms of your "Is it suitable?" in the *body* of your question, almost certainly not.

In the sense that you could also write accounting applications in BCPL, or web servers in COBOL-85, then yes, it's probably doable. Whether it's a good idea, that's a *different* matter.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa867122.aspx.

Comment: The answer given here: “possibly”, is incorrect.  The question asks if X++ is “suitable” for games and web sites.  The correct answer is definitely not.  Reasons are numerous, surveying developers on games/web suitability would land X++ far from the top 10.   

What if the question asked “can it be done”, instead of “is it suitable”?  For most turing complete languages in use today, the answer would be technically yes.  However unsuitable or inefficient, in principle TC languages can be contorted to create games or web sites with very little library support.  But it’s not always a good idea.

Comment: @whitneyland, the *title* itself is "can it be used?" which is what I based the answer on. I'll clarify ...

Comment: Thank you.  Looks like we were both tripped up by this ambiguity.  I've changed my -1 to +1. Ideally, the title should match.  I wouldn't mind editing the title to be consistent but don't want to cause extra work with your updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

X++ is targeted for at business ERP domain and it would not support game or generic website development very well.

And X++ is a rather slow language in itself. It has it strengths around database access.

Answer (score 4):

x++ is a language that is primarily used to customize Microsoft's ERP package known as Dynamics AX. Inside of the Dynamics environment, you could develop games (Dynamics does include a version of Tetris in the code tutorials).

Due to the fact that it is not generally used outside of the Dynamics AX environment, I would not suggest learning it for the purpose of writing games.

Comment: I have recently read that X++ will be able to be compiled to CIL in AX 2012, which means that it is getting closer to being a .Net language. It may soon be possible to use X++ outside of AX.

Answer (score 0):

X++ is used only for the Microsoft Dynamics ERP development(for now). It's an OOP language however it's scope is out of game dev.